# I do not have access to the rails command in my application folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvmrc

I have rails installed on a machine (Ubuntu 12.04) and have used for a couple of Rails projects.  I have access to the `rails` command in my home folder and any other folder I create on my machine.  I created a new directory for a project.  I also created a .rvmrc file with the following content:

```
rvm --create ruby-2.0.0-p0@gemset
```

After I created the .rvmrc file I ran the following commands:

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p0
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0
rvm gemset create project.me
rvm gemset use project.me
```

Everything looks good up to the point.  When I try to create the rails project with:

```
rails new .
```

I get the following error:

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

What do I not understand?  I know that I can create a new project with

```
rails new project.me
```

And everything will work fine, but why is this not working?  Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't have rails gem installed in your gemset.

Try out gem install rails, after using the specific gemset.

Comment: That was it.  Why do I not have access to rails in this situation?  I assume because it is not spelled out in the .rvmrc file.  If this is true, is there any way I can specify it in the file and add it to my gemset immediately?   Thanks again for your time.

Comment: you can add a file in your app folder named .rvmrc and add the following in it

`rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p0@project.me`

In this case you will always switch to this gemset when you cd in your project dir.